# Deploy a Visual Studio 2010 C# project with a third party API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, api, deployment, executable

How do I convert a Microsoft Visual 2010 C# project in to a stand alone .exe set up so that I can install it on PC and use it? The project uses third party dlls and the Emgu CV API. Can anyone show me a good tutorial about how to do this or tell me the steps here. I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create an .msi (WiX Setup project) and an .exe (WiX Bootstrapper project). By default the .msi will be embedded in the .exe.

The setup project should include your application project deliverables as well as third party DLLs. For info see this [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_votive_project.htm).

The bootstrapper project should include your .msi, Microsoft .NET 3.0 Framework and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) that [Emgu CV needs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Getting_the_Dependency). For info see this [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm).

This [website](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/) has good tutorials but it does not cover Bootstrapper projects.